# How to copy a class in C++?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have class `A`

```
class A{
public:
    A(const A&) {};
    A() {};
    ~A() {};
    bool bln; 
    B b;
}
```

If I write

```
A *a2;
a2 = new A(*a);
```

where `a` is an `A` object, then `a2->b` seems different to `a->b`.

How can I exactly copy `a` to `a2`?

Comment: Are you implementing this class or using some arbitrary class template?

Comment: Also, the provided snippet exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: This may be better suited as a `struct`.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: I am implementing this class. 'a' is an 'A' object, and I would copy its content in another object 'a2'

Comment: Don't forget that if you need special handling to copy  a class, you probably also need special handling, an `operator=` for correct assignment.

Comment: @Alessandro while your class doesn't have pointers as attribute or special feature it is useless to define the copy contructor and operator=, the compiler does that for you

Comment: @NathanOliver I would just understand how to copy an object A to another object A. Or better, I would know where I am wrong in this example.

Comment: @Alessandro in your example `A(const A&) {};` does nothing, so the copy constructor does nothing and the new instance is not initialized

Comment: I get that but this is such a basic principal that if you are having trouble with it you might be missing/having trouble with others.  A good C++ book will make sure you have a solid foundation which will help you greatly.  C++ can be/is a very complex and nuanced language and takes a lot of work to master (I'm still working on it and I've been using it for over 10 years)

Comment: @bruno Thanks, from what I understood that line should have been sufficient. So, I am wrong. I am not a C++ programmer, I just need to know ho to exactly copy a class.

Comment: @Alessandro it is like if you define `void f(){}`, that function does nothing at all, is the same for your copy constructor. If you define the copy constructor you have to do all the necessary work explicitly, there is nothing implicit

Comment: So, isn't there a C++ function that copies an object? I see it is a basic question, but I cannot find a basic answer

Comment: @Alessandro No, there is not. A constructor is responsible for explicitly initializing any class members that need to be initialized (ones that do not have their own default constructors). And a copy constructor is responsible for explicitly copying any relevant values from the source instance to the instance being constructed. If you need to define constructors at all (versus let the compiler generate them for you) then you need to do the relevant work to implement them properly.

Answer (score 1):

`bln` is not being initialized in any of `A`'s constructors.  `b` is only being default constructed in both constructors, and is not being copied at all in the copy constructor.

Try this:

```
class A
{
public:
    bool bln; 
    B b;

    A() : bln(false) {}
    A(const A &src) : bln(src.bln), b(src.b) {}
};
```

A better option is to simply let the compiler generate a default copy constructor for you, which will effectively be the same as above:

```
class A
{
public:
    bool bln;
    B b;

    A() : bln(false) {}
};
```

Or, in C++11 and later, you can do use:

```
class A
{
public:
    bool bln = false;
    B b;

    // these are optional in this case and can be omitted
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = default;
};
```

Comment: Why do I need to initialize bln?

Comment: @Alessandro otherwise it will have an *indeterminate* value. Simple POD types, like `bool`, do not have default values, especially when used as class members. You have to initialize them explicitly.